# Building a query in appmaker with "or"

Tags: google-app-maker

So say I am using a form to build a query against my datasource (i've come so far in two weeks! I can do this!), how do I make it more complex?

What if I want books by austen that include the word "pride" AND books by gabaldon that contain the word "Snow"

the individual queries would be

```
widget.datasource.query.filters['author']._contains = "austen";
widget.datasource.query.filters['title']._contains = "pride";
```

and

```
widget.datasource.query.filters['author']._contains = "gabaldon";
widget.datasource.query.filters['title']._contains = "snow";
```

in pseudosql it would be

```
select * from table
where
((author like 'austen') and (title like 'snow'))
or
((author like 'gabaldon') and (title like 'pride'))
```

Is there a way to  filter a data source on a complex query like this and cut out the whole widget.datasource aspect? I'd be fine with using a calculated table.

**Edit**: Ok i'm making some progress towards the kind of functionality I need, can anyone tell me why this works:

```
widget.datasource.query.filters.document_name._contains = 'x';
```

but this does not?

```
widget.datasource.query.parameters.v1 = "x";

widget.datasource.query.where = 'document_name contains :v1';
```

this also doesn't work:

```
widget.datasource.query.where = 'document_name contains "x"';
```

Comment: Have you considered using query builder for your datasource? You could do the following `(author contains :AuthorParam1 and title contains :TitleParam1) or (author contains :AuthorParam2 and title contains :TitleParam2)`. Then bind your first author textbox in your form to `@datasource.query.parameters.AuthorParam1` and your first title textbox in your form to `@datasource.query.parameters.TitleParam1` and then do the same for the second set of textboxes just for the second set of parameters.

Comment: Where do you enter the querybuilder code? (that might work!)

Comment: In your datasource switch from 'Query Script' to 'Query Builder'. This is located right under your datasource name where it says 'Query' and is presented as a radiogroup in your datasource settings.

Comment: Ok, checking out this idea

Comment: I've decided that I really NEED a way to use sql to query the table, because of how I want to build the queries (potentially many different fields not just two, and different sets of configurations). I can build SQL queries with GAS, I just need to figure out how to execute them against the database.

Comment: query.where might get me there.

Comment: If you need your query fully customizable like being able to choose which field you are querying then sticking with query script is probably your best option and from there I would suggest to introduce all your dynamic fields as query parameters and then constructing your 'where' clause from there. The comment I had posted under your 'Dynamic Query' question still should be applicable as this should get you going in the right direction at least. But if you have specific questions how to apply this here, feel free to ask.

Comment: SEE EDIT ABOVE in post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196346/discussion-between-markus-malessa-and-j-g).